# Determine pointwise limit function and check for uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I've tried this question in different forms multiple times and continue to get the wrong answer.

Let $x_n(t)$ be defined by
$$x_n(t) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & 0 \leq t \leq 4/n \\
      4n & 4/n < t < 7/n \\
      0 & 7/n \leq t \leq 2 
   \end{cases}$$
Determine the pointwise limit function $x$ and determine whether or not the convergence is uniform.

Any help is appreciated. I'm beyond stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The pointwise limit is the zero function, and note that $\sup_{x\in[0,2]}x_{n}(t)$ becomes more and more larger as $n$ tends larger, so can you conclude that whether the convergence is uniform or not?